# How to keep everyone on team in sync with repo?

Tags: repository, collaboration

This is probably a very basic question, but I have never worked on a team before and I'm not sure if there is an obvious answer or if I'm too bad at googling. Regardless, I can't find a clear answer to how this is done in practice.

Let's say I'm on a team with 9 other people working part time on a school project for the duration of a semester. Using some sort of CI with Github, we integrate code into our repo anywhere from a few times a week to multiple times per day. How does everyone on the team sync up their local machines with that Github repo? Ideally, we would want to simulate a real project in a work environment.

It's often explained in the context of a git workflow just using an arrow, but what I want to know is what that arrow looks like in practice, either through personal anecdotes or software/script recommendations (in case the process is automated).

Comment: Entire books have been written about this very topic so I doubt you will really get a satisfactory answer in the Q&A format of this site.  Of course there is not always one solution to this problem, a lot of it has to do with the nature of the project, the size and culture of the team as well.  I suggest reading up on theories of source control systems, Git and Git Flow, and various models of open source project contributions to get an idea of how they manage multiple ongoing development efforts and coordinating them.  If you have a more specific question in your studies then please post back.

Comment: This question is focused enough. I was 30 seconds away from finishing an answer.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Apologies, do you think you know how to edit the question to focus it to some specific topics so we can reopen it?  I see at least 10 different questions here.

Comment: @maple_shaft I apologize if the question seems unfocused. I've read a bit about git workflows, but this step is either not explained at all, or just explained using an arrow, and I want to know what that arrow looks like in practice. Anecdotes, software/script recommendations (in case of some sort of automation) - any information would be helpful. I could edit out the sub-questions, but I added them to help guide an answer.

Comment: @maple_shaft I updated the question. Let me know if you find that it's still not focused enough.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I reopened the question if you wanted to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say you are working on a feature branch and want your code changes to be nearer to the tip of the spear. There are two operations to do so, a merge commit or a rebase. There are pros and cons to both.

Other than that, it is a good practice to keep feature branches short-lived to reduce the extra effort put into reconciling code.

When working together on a particular area of the code, you can pair program, or you can use techniques like introducing key interfaces early and putting mock implementations when another person works in that area.

Answer (score 2):

At a certain point, you have to pull, or your pull request CI build will fail, or your git push will fail, or something. After a while, you get in the habit of pulling before you create a pull request.

The other time you generally want to pull is right before you start on a task, especially if you work in several different repos and they are not always all up to date. Just two days ago, I figured out a change that needed to be made, then pulled from master and created a branch to start the actual work, and discovered someone else had made the change overnight. My habit of getting synced up at the start of a task saved me a lot of redundant work. I formed that habit after getting burned a few times.

Generally, I try not to go more than half a day between pull requests, but sometimes tasks take longer, or other team members are working rapidly in closely related code. In those cases, I will pull about twice a day, for the same reason I pull at the start. It has saved me from a lot of redundant work in the past. However, any more frequently than that means I feel like all I'm doing is solving merge conflicts. There's a balance you will find for yourself.

In summary, it's a manual process, but the automation and your collaborators prod you to pull on a regular cadence.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers have some good points about branches being short lived, and making it a personal practice to pull in new changes on a regular basis. There is still one fundamental and extremely difficult piece missing: **communication**.

*You* can make it a practice to keep branches short lived.

*You* can make it a practice to pull in changes on a regular basis.

The question remains about how to get the *team* in sync, and this is where communication comes in to play.

Each time code is pushed to a shared branch of any sort then the whole team at least needs an email or notification about this happening. Same thing for pull requests being created, updated or closed. Many tools will send these notifications automatically. If there is no automation for this communication, then it needs to be manual. This communication should be a flag for each person that they have new work to incorporate into their own at a convenient time of their choosing.

But even automated communication is not enough without defining an agreed upon team process, and then trusting teammates to follow it. This is where the techniques that Karl and Martin outline in their answers manifest themselves.

So really it is:

1. Define and agree upon how the team does work.
2. Leverage communication tools built into things like GitHub to keep people abreast of changes.
3. Do your part to actually do the process the team has agreed to.
4. Trust other teammates to follow the process.
5. Help coach teammates so they learn and value the process too.